# How do I install python 3.6.5 on my Ubuntu 19.10 that already contains python 3.7.5?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I will accept two possible solutions:

1. Both versions are installed side by side.
2. 3.7.5 is removed and 3.6.5 is then installed.

Comment: Just take it from an older release. That was you get proper Ubuntu package.  Don't mess with the system via hacks.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3.6-minimal

Comment: You cannot uninstall python 3.7 in ubuntu 19.10, that is a critical system component.

Comment: There is a ppa (https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for getting any somewhat sensible python version into LTS releases. Unfortunately 19.10 is not an LTS release.

Comment: It doesn't matter, that still helps and is close to my earlier comment: you can code from an _earlier_ PPA on a later release. Just not the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use `pyenv`.

https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/

If you have installed all packages and dependencies you can install different version like this:

```
pyenv install -v 3.6.5
```

Comment: Right i use normally pyenv but found the other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can install another python version side by side.

You can see https://www.python.org/ftp/python/ to get a link of your desired version of python. Then download and install.

Here are possible steps

1. Run `sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev openssl` to install dependencies need for compiling
2. Run `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tgz` to downlaod
3. Run `tar -xf Python-3.6.5.tgz` to extract
4. Run `cd Python-3.6.5` to get into code directory
5. Run `./configure` to configure and generate the necessary build files
6. Run `make` to compile
7. Run `sudo make install` to finally install

New version is installed and available to use.